# Upgrade Umbraco existing project from version 4.11.8 to version 7.5.4

Tags: umbraco, upgrade

I have successfully upgraded version 4.8.1 to 4.11.8 (I'm trying to upgrade to each minor versions incrementally step by step) but when i'm trying to upgrade the version 4.11.8 to 6.0.0, then templates, macros, and all others loading perfectly at backend side except content and document types, Please help to get rid of this issue.. Thanks in advance :)
[Check here - Error Displayed in Firebug in Firefox Console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5v5K.png)
[Check here - "ajax" XHR request and response coming from the source trying to pull content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEHI8.png)

Comment: Can you ellaborate more? Do you get an error? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I am not getting any type of error, the problem is with loading list of "content" and "document types" from backend that i have in my existing project, I mean i'm not able to see a single document type in the list as well as not a single content in the list, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try and load this up with firebug or chrome dev tools (or similar) - you should see an "ajax" XHR request and response coming from the source trying to pull content. Inspecting the response from this should give you some more information.

Comment: Hi @user369142, Thanks for reply, I checked in firebug from firefox console window - it displays error something like this:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name &#39;cmsPropertyTypeGroup&#39;.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action
`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3242916

look at the attached screenshot in my question for more description, Thanks again :)